# Why does FireFox send a request automatically to the first result in Google?

Tags: firefox

In FireFox 3.6.1 (a fresh install), I am seeing a request sent to the first search result (Google) without user interaction.

Why is this?

Comment: this is a programming website, yet your question is not related to programming whatsoever. `why is this?`

Comment: it is absolutely related to programming. I am working a a SERP scraper

Comment: @user its related to *your* programming project, but not programming in general.  I might have to research health record laws for a medical record storage program, but that doesn't make it programming related.

Comment: would you consider HTML a programming language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers are set up to preload some links in a page, in order to minimize perceived delays.  Google actually supports this.  For example, When i google for "blah", the first result includes this code:

```
<link rel=prefetch href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blah">
```

A browser that supports this "microformat", or has a plugin installed that does, might load the page before it's requested, assuming (quite correctly, in many cases) that a user will click on the first search result they see.